# Href url match using prototype js library

Tags: javascript, regex, prototypejs

In   my system, i am using prototype js.

Now i want to `match any href with using href.match and do want something`.

Try someting  done but it create issue express

```
Suppose: my url
```

> www.example.com/customer/account/login/an/aaa?333=sddssdsd,sasaas

**Want to like this:**

If any href contain  `customer/account/login/` then my condition should be works.
try this below:

```
   if(accountlink.href.match(/\/customer\/account\/login\//)){
//do someting
}
```

But this is condition, i also working whenever  url:

- `www.example.com/customer/account/aaa/`
- `www.example.com/aaa/account/login/an/`

I does no want to this.

Want just like if href contain `customer/account/login/` then it work.

Please help  me.

Comment: Your regex doesn't match `www.example.com/customer/account/aaa/` or `www.example.com/aaa/account/login/an/`, do you mean you don't want it to match `www.example.com/customer/account/login/aaa/` and `www.example.com/aaa/customer/account/login/an/`

Comment: yes..  this is want?....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use vanilla javascript to do this:

```
var url = 'www.example.com/customer/account/login/an/aaa?333=sddssdsd,sasaas'
if (url.indexOf('customer/account/login/') > -1) {
  // Do your stuff
}
```

Ref.: (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)